# Spring Cloud API Gateway not forwarding to Netflix DGS graphql endpoint

Tags: spring, kotlin, graphql, netflix-dgs

I'm trying to migrate a project over to using DGS but I'm running into problems with the API gateway.

I have a Spring/DGS service running on `http://localhost:3000`, so the graphql queries are going to `http://localhost:3000/graphql`.

My API gateway has a route config:

```
@Bean
fun routes(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder): RouteLocator{
  return builder.routes()
    .route{it.path("/v1/users/**").uri("http://localhost:3000")}
    .route{it.path("/userService/graphql").uri("http://localhost:3000/graphql)}
    .build()
}
```

When I use `actuator` to check the routes I get:

```
{
    "predicate": "Paths: [/userService/graphql], match trailing slash: true",
    "route_id": "ecacf5ee-9544-485b-8a4e-4c2d02b94b8d",
    "filters": [],
    "uri": "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
    "order": 0
}
```

And when I go to `http://localhost:3000/graphiql` I can using the graphiql UI to run queries on my user service. If I send graphql queries to `http://localhost:3000/graphql` I get a response, but if I send the same query to `http://localhost:8080/userService/graphql` I get a `404`. Further, if I try to hit the REST endpoints on `localhost:3000` using the gateway like `localhost:8080/v1/users/user/{userId}` I get the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each route an id.

```
@Bean
fun routes(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder): RouteLocator{
  return builder.routes()
    .route("users") {it.path("/v1/users/**").uri("http://localhost:3000")}
    .route("graphql") {it.path("/userService/graphql").uri("http://localhost:3000/graphql)}
    .build()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no go on that one. Still getting the `404`